# Way of speeding up a vertex distance calculation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've been struggling with an algorithm tied to comparisons with 3d triangle vectors. Unfortunately its very slow in places and I've gone back and forth on different methods to try and improve it. One thing I'm struggling with is speeding up a distance calculation.

I have two groups of triangles which have been broken down to three points each of which has a 3d float vector (xyz). The calculations I'm using are :

```
    diffverts = numpy.zeros( (  ntris*3, ntesttris*3, 3 ), dtype = 'float32')
    diffverts += triverts.reshape(ntris*3, 1, 3 )
    diffverts -= ttriverts.reshape(1, ntesttris*3, 3 )
    vertdist = ( diffverts[:,:,0]**2 + diffverts[:,:,1]**2 + diffverts[:,:,2]**2 ) ** 0.5
```

this calculation is faster than :

```
    diffverts = triverts.reshape(ntris*3, 1, 3 ) - ttriverts.reshape(1, ntesttris*3, 3 )
    vertdist = ( diffverts[:,:,0]**2 + diffverts[:,:,1]**2 + diffverts[:,:,2]**2 ) ** 0.5
```

Is there a faster method to populate the diff vert part (which takes longest) and/or the distance part which is also quite time consuming? This code is called a lot of times due to the number of groups to test. Also, trying to do it just on indexes to the verts causes me other issues with further calculations when trying to get back to some boolean tests (i.e. this is only one of a set of calculations so keeping at the tri point level works best.

I'm using numpy and python

Comment: I don't know about numpy too much, but if you only need relative distances then leave off the square root. Square root is a pretty slow operation in general. Also, I'm not sure how it optimizes that but sometimes "pow(n, 2)" kinds of things are slower than "n * n".

Comment: Hi thanks Hans, yes I may be able to leave off the squareroot though I need to apply the distance in soem form to my results later. However, I don't think that helps the speed that much (relatively). In this example through the basic set of loops I'm going through (ie with all the groups) the setting up of the diff verts part is about 60-70% of the time v the actual distance part being about 30-40%

Comment: What kind of sizes are you working with?

Comment: Its a mix,  most are probbaly about 100 of each set of tris but can vary up to 1000+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that brute force testing of all triangles versus eachother takes quadratic time. It is better to use a datastructure which is specialized to perform such computations. Luckily, scipy contains one.

Take a look at scipy.spatial.cKDTree. The help should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'll have a look at that. However, doing the calculations for 3 types of angle calculations also on each tri point are roughly a tenth of the speed. The basic population of the subtraction of the vectors here is the most time consuming thing. I don't know if there is a better way to do that set up.

Comment: There is; if you use cKDTree, the whole brute force substraction of each point versus all others never happens.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use cKDTree to get a) the points within a set distance. b) the actual distance and c) a Boolean array triverts*ttriverts in size to say which ones were valid? Unless I can get to all 3 steps its not much use I'm afraid. I need b to use later and I need c to compare with 3 other angle tests.

Comment: I looked at the cKDTree decscription but in the end tried scipy.spatial.distance. That seems to create the right size vertdist for me which I can then do the tests against. In the end the time using this was approximately the same as just the vertdist calculation ie excluding the diff verts calculation. So it gave me a 60% improvement. I need to test end results to be sure. Also not sure if part of the issue is memory related so will also try chunking to lower the sizes.

Comment: If you actually need every distance between every vector, it's going to be quadratic time anyway.

Comment: If you do indeed need all distances, your problem can not be significantly accelerated. But from your description, it is not at all clear to me this is the case. If your points need to be within a set distance, why bother doing any other tests on them? You could filter for points being within a set distance first; and then do the other tests only on this much smaller set of point pairs.

Comment: I only needed a within distance and within 3 other angle tests first. Then only for the pairs that pass that do I need the distance. so I can use the results of than angle test and distances to set a value for the specific vertex. That was why i was wanting to do it in a series of tests and why at least I thought doing it at the tri point level was better. Not sure I am really gaining much if anything from trying to add cKDTree into that but still plan to try and report back if it does prove useful.

Comment: ParsingError; in other words, I still don't get what you mean. If at any point you filter pairs by distance, this is where you should start, to cut out the O(N^2) boogeyman.

Comment: OK, finally got to test cKDTree out and it did speed up things significantly once I redid the code to handle the returned pairs. Its calculation itself was a reasonable improvement but using only the pairs for the other calculations helped a lot. I also decided I didn't really need the distance bit so that also helped. I used the query_pairs option. Having used it the only thing that would be nicer is if it had an option to get the same type of pair output but from 2 different trees. I saw query_ball_tree did this but returned a list of lists instead.

Comment: np.array(tree.sparse_distance_matrix(othertree).keys()) may be what you are after

Answer (score 0):

I think diffverts is taking up enough memory to cause cache misses. Unfortunately while this solution is very elegant, you're probably better off computing the whole distance in one go, to avoid having to save an n*m*3 array of intermediate values. As ugly as it is, I would just do nested for loops.

Comment: I also use some inner calculations to work out the three angles calculations. They are approximately 10* faster for the same sizes. I also did some tests earlier against some nested loops but they were slower. As it is the number of groups being tested is nested anyway in order to chunk the loop.

Comment: When I tired to run the comparison against the orginal (see comment in first answer) I got a memory error so you are likely right that part of the issue is tied to the sizes. I'll chunk down and see if it helps.